# Convert SQL command to MVC or lambda code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda

I want this query in lambda expression:

```
Insert into Tbl_Bill (EmpID, TotalBill, BillByEmployee, BillBySBI, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate, OrderIDs) 
    select 
        EmpID, Sum(TotalBill), Sum(TotalBill), Sum(TotalBill),
        MIN(CreatedDate), MIN(CreatedDate), COUNT(OrderID) 
    from 
        Tbl_Order 
    group by 
        EmpID;
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 different sums, all producing the same number but named differently?

Comment: @Milney its just for testing purpose.Please see below answer then you know why i use three different names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var queryTbl_Bill =
                                    from Tbl_Order in db.Tbl_Order
                                    group Tbl_Order by new
                                    {
                                        Tbl_Order.EmpID
                                    } into g
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        g.Key.EmpID,
                                        Column1 = g.Sum(p => p.TotalBill),
                                        Column2 = g.Sum(p => p.TotalBill),

                                        Column3 = g.Sum(p => p.TotalBill),
                                        Column4 = g.Min(p => p.CreatedDate),
                                        Column5 = g.Min(p => p.CreatedDate),
                                        Column6 = g.Count(p => p.OrderID != null)


                                    };
                                            foreach (var q in queryTbl_Bill)
                                            {
                                                decimal sbi = 0, emp = 0;
                                                if (q.Column1 < 100.0M) 
                                                {
                                                    sbi = q.Column1 * 0.75M;
                                                    emp = q.Column1 * 0.25M;
                                                }
                                                else if (q.Column1 > 100.0M)
                                                {
                                                    sbi = 75.0M;
                                                    decimal temp = q.Column1 - 100.0M;
                                                    emp = temp + 25.0M;
                                                }
                                                Tbl_Bill iTbl_Bill = new Tbl_Bill
                                                {

                                                    EmpID = q.EmpID,
                                                    TotalBill = q.Column1,
                                                    BillByEmployee = emp,
                                                    BillBySBI = sbi,
                                                    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                                    UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                                    OrderIDs = q.Column6.ToString(),
                                                    Status=true
                                                };
                                                db.Tbl_Bill.Add(iTbl_Bill);
                                            }
                                            db.SaveChanges();
```

i got answer using **linqer**

Answer (score 0):

Use LinqPad, its a superb tool to queries to linq queries